# jQuery - event handler to detect if HTML select option has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

How can I detect in jQuery when any option in a select tag has been changed?

For example [pseudocode]:

```
event handler function -> option changed(){      
  //do some stuff
}
```

EDIT:

I have the following select:

```
<select id = "selectattribute">
  <OPTION VALUE="0">Choose Attribute</OPTION>
  <?php echo($options);?>
</select>
```

I am trying this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectattribute").change(function() {
     alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  });
});
```

Nothing happens...the function isn;t triggering.

EDIT: it works when I use `$("#select")` instead of `$("#selectattribute")...can you not apply it to particular select tags?`

Comment: You attach a listener to the select element for the change event. You can use jQuery (or any of a number of libraries), or a few lines of plain script, or an in-line handler.

Comment: @RobG: You really shouldn't propose inline-handler...

Comment: have you tried different browsers?

Comment: @Saxoier - you really shouldn't express opinions in a technical forum without providing sound technical reasons for them.

Comment: Can you supply the code once it has been rendered by php

Comment: @RobG: With your high score and most answers tagged with 'JavaScript' you should know that you should not mix HTML with inline JS and inline CSS because these files are hard to maintain (distinguish content and visual presentation). You can read it in *many* answers.

Comment: @Saxoier - I don't know anything of the sort. I do know to consider all alternatives and their pros and cons and not follow dogma with no reasoned argument. Inline handlers have many benefits, they are no more difficult to maintain than data- or class attributes. Dynamically added listeners have their issues too and aren't always the best solution.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, HTML 5 data-attributes also belong to this inline contents whereas classes (and ids) are only anchor-points and therefore far easier to manage if properly used.

Comment: I don't see that maintaining one kind of attribute value is any different to maintaining another kind. I'm not saying "always use inline handlers", I'm saying that they are a reasonable option to be considered on their merits for particular cases, they shouldn't be dismissed without due consideration just because they aren't hip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [jQuery docs regarding the change handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
<form>
  <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

The event handler can be bound to the text input and the select box:

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Comment: Hi I saw that and implemented it but it isn;t working...see my edited post

Comment: It should be working according to the code you posted in your edit. See the fiddle link by "Jon P" in another answer here. Your posted code works when isolated. So it's possible you have other things in the rest of the page that is messing it up--you may have to post the whole page HTML. Are you using the id name more than once? Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Your Code works in Firefox using the mouse, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHfjd/).

However using the keyboard is a different matter as per [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6067)

To work around this I've added a key up handler to remove focus from the element then re-focus, as per [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq74y/)

If the change event is not triggering when using the mouse, check the options rendered by your php code. Look for structures that might be "breaking" the select tag.

Comment: ...quite solid answer. Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").change(function() {})
```

Comment: you need to look at the docs for jquery selectors  `$("select")` would select all `<select>` tags.  `$("#select")` would select all dom elements with an `id='select'` attribute.  To get only the select dom element you want, use its dom id in the selector

Answer (score 0):

Try bind:

```
  $("#selectattribute").bind('change', function() {
     alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  });
```

or change function in jQUery:

```
  $("#selectattribute").change(
     function() {
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
     }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another tag which id is named "selectattribute".The tag id should be unique.If there is more than one id,jQuery will use the first one founded.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JQuery is not loaded,check first that it is loaded

```
    //case if mini jQueryis not used replace with window.jQuery
    if (window.$) {
    console.debug('jQuery is loaded ');
    } else {
    console.debug('jQuery is not loaded ');
    }
```